# Rails - Editing Attachments with CarrierWave & Cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, attachment, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have two models, **Evidence** and **Attachment**. An evidence has many attachments, and I'm using the Cocoon gem with a nested form to create/edit Evidences (and their associated Attachments). I'm using CarrierWave to handle the attachment uploads.

I can easily create an Evidence with multiple attachments, but once an Evidence has been created, I can't seem to add additional attachments. The form works fine but the attachments do not save.

Here's the basic setup of my code:

(app/models/evidence.rb)

```
class Evidence < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

(app/models/attachment.rb)

```
require 'digest'

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  attr_accessor :override_filename
  delegate :file, to: :attachment

  after_create do
    AttachmentFilesizeJob.perform_later(self)
    AttachmentMd5sumJob.perform_later(self)
  end
end
```

(app/views/evidences/_form.html.erb)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@evidence) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Attachments</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>File</th>
            <th colspan="1"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="attachments_table">
          <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |af| %>
            <% if af.object.attachment.nil? %>
              <%= render 'attachment_fields', f: af %>
            <% else %>
              <tr>
                <td><code><%= af.object.attachment %></code><%= attachment_download_button(af.object) %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>          
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div id="links">
        <%=
          link_to_add_association 'Add Attachment', f, :attachments,
            :"data-association-insertion-node" => 'tbody#attachments_table',
            :"data-association-insertion-method" => 'append',
            class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
          %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

(app/views/evidences/_attachment_fields.html.erb)

```
<tr class="nested-fields form-inline form-table-row">
  <td>
    <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

What can I do here to enable adding attachments to an already created evidence? Everything works fine when creating a new evidence, but not when editing.

Params on Evidence#create (with two attachments - strains1.csv and strains2.csv)

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"rKq1zaDAc1w1GlgF8Q+ejjVuA6YXYc5EfhCwHXltK/4vijOJw1ffeHUY3GWSSmKLevbfxBSwMAeEIjuHw4BIhQ==",
>   "evidence"=>{"source"=>"", "notes"=>"", "mutation_id"=>"",
>   "attachments_attributes"=>{"1476226326082"=>{"attachment"=>#,
>   @original_filename="strains1.csv", @content_type="text/csv",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"evidence[attachments_attributes][1476226326082][attachment]\";
>   filename=\"strains1.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">},
>   "1476226412102"=>{"attachment"=>#,
>   @original_filename="strains2.csv", @content_type="text/csv",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"evidence[attachments_attributes][1476226412102][attachment]\";
>   filename=\"strains2.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">}}},
>   "commit"=>"Create Evidence"}

These two attachments save fine. Then I try to edit the evidence and add an additional attachment, "strains3.csv" - here are the params on Evidence#update:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"QsYgeVnsTf8oegVaJ733JD93MPxnH1aXutC9dDDAf53B5qY9Onvh22h4gTpE+AshcO/snmTOqNRA4jbuii0c5g==",
>   "evidence"=>{"source"=>"", "notes"=>"", "mutation_id"=>"",
>   "attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"87"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"88"},
>   "1476226681765"=>{"attachment"=>#,
>   @original_filename="strains3.csv", @content_type="text/csv",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"evidence[attachments_attributes][1476226681765][attachment]\";
>   filename=\"strains3.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">}}},
>   "commit"=>"Update Evidence", "id"=>"1"}

The third attachment never gets uploaded or saved.

Comment: Maybe this issue is related: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/311 ? Because it sounds awfully similar. Otherwise you might have callbacks/validation which only work on create and not update (or save) or the other way round? How does your strong parameters declaration look?

Comment: Thanks - I tried using the carrierwave-base64 gem but still encounter the same issue. My evidence params are as such:   params.require(:evidence).permit(:id, :source, :notes, :mutation_id, attachments_attributes: [
        :attachment, :id
      ])

Comment: So no different validations/callbacks on create/update i presume? What is posted to the controller on update? (when adding attachments)

Comment: @nathanvda Edited to show the params here. There is an after_create callback in the Attachment model, but changing it to after_save doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: The data posted to the server/controller seem perfectly fine, so I am stumped. From the code you've shown I see nothing that would cause this.The `after_create` callback in Attachment is ok (because you are always adding _new_ attachments), I would suspect a validation in `Evidence` to block saving somehow.

Comment: @nathanvda I figured it out - it was a typo in my EvidencesController#update method. Thanks for your help here!